# splitting up a conduit chain

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have this conduit expression which works:

```
main1 = runResourceT
       $ CB.sourceHandle stdin
      $$ CB.lines
      =$ Cl.concatMap matches
      =$ Cl.mapMaybe readDouble
      =$ Cl.map fst
      =$ Cl.map bucket
      =$ Cl.map (BS.pack . show)
      =$ Cl.map (\x -> x <> BS.pack "\n")
      =$ CB.sinkHandle stdout
```

I'm having trouble splitting it up into two pieces, i.e. something like:

```
source = CB.sourceHandle stdin
  $$ CB.lines
  =$ Cl.concatMap matches
  =$ Cl.mapMaybe readDouble
  =$ Cl.map fst
  =$ Cl.map bucket

sink = Cl.map (BS.pack . show)
  =$ Cl.map (\x -> x <> BS.pack "\n")
  =$ CB.sinkHandle stdout
```

so that I can use:

```
runResourceT $ source =$ sink
```

or whatever... The error message I get from the type-checker is somewhat inscrutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `source` side, replace all the operators with `$=`, which is the "fuse a source with a conduit" operator, aka left-fusion.